# jquery infinite scroll plugin - loading and memory issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, out-of-memory, infinite-scroll

I am using infinate scroll plugin (by Paul Irish).  I want to use custom functions when the next page is loading and when the maxPage is reached.

I have tried the below based on the documentation, however this starts the loading function but doesn't ever call the finished function.  Its not calling the next page either when I look in the console.  What am I missing?

```
    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: "div.paginate",
        nextSelector: "div.paginate a",
        itemSelector: "div.element",
        maxPage: 5,
        loading: {
            start: function(){
                  alert('started');
            },
            finished: function(){
                  alert('finsihed loading');
            }
        }
    },
    function(newElements) {

        var $newElements = $(newElements).css({opacity: 0});
        //remove the first item
        $newElements.splice(0, 1);

            $container.isotope('appended', $newElements);

        }

    });
});
```

The scrolling could go on for pages and pages until the browser crashes due to memory issues,  I therefore need to stop infinite scrolling when the current page gets to maxPage and allow the user to select a "Load More" button.  Hopefully solving memory issues.

This is discussed in the link below but I cannot find any further documentation on how to do this exactly and cann't even get the above sample to work.

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/issues/300

Comment: What does ajaxLoader do?

Comment: What version of jquery.infinitescroll.js are you using? It seems the options changed as of v2.0.

Comment: Im using the latest version,2.0b2.120519.

Comment: ajaloader disables all links and mouseovers and displays a loading image

Comment: please fix errors in your code example, you have an extra } inside the infinitescroll parentheses

Comment: Does the `start` alert trigger on every page? If so you might be open to implement an own solution with counting a variable up and using an `if` or so? I would detail that in an answer... :)

Comment: The start function triggers when I first start to scroll the page then it doesn't do the ajax call, it isnt calling the next page when I look in the console. if I remove the start function, it does call the next page.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure it works will the minimum options (plus console debug messages):

```
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: "div.paginate",
    nextSelector: "div.paginate a",
    itemSelector: "div.element",
    debug: true
});
```

If it does, add in options until it breaks.

I recommend debugging the start/finished functions in the console, like this:

```
    loading: {
        start: function(){
              console.log('started');
        },
        finished: function(){
              console.log('finsihed loading');
        }
    }
```

Consider adding the `errorCallback` option to debug ajax issues.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.  I have added alerts in the start and finish functions.  The start one alerts but the finish one doesn't.  It isnt calling the next page when I look in the console.  See changes above

Comment: Could it be the missing comma between `start` and `finished`?

Comment: there is a comma, sorry I just hadn't added it above,  Its there now!

Comment: No errors, I just get the following:  ["determinePath", ["index.php?p=", "&curr=GBP"]]
jquery...roll.js (line 241)
pixelsFromNavToBottom: 70.4000244140625
jquery...roll.js (line 239)
["Binding", "bind"]
jquery...roll.js (line 241)
["math:", 0, 70.4000244140625]

Comment: Hmm, there may be a problem with the `nextSelector`. What is the href of `div.paginate a`? And is there only one `a`? You may have to use `a:first`.

Comment: I dont think it is that as it all works fine using the default loading images.  It stopped loading when I changed the defaults to use custom functions.  There isn't much documentation on this...

Comment: If you say so. It just looks like your path is an array rather than a string, is all.